# How to visualize 3D fit

Tags: plotting, fitting, visualization

I have a data set of `x,y,z` values and I fit a function of `x,y` to the data. This works, but I can't come up with a nice way to visualize the data. 3D plots are not very clear on paper and a contour plot of two data sets doesn't work either. What would be a clear and simple way to show the data and the fit?

```
data = Import["https://pastebin.com/raw/mTUJAZrM"];
fit = NonlinearModelFit[
       data, 
       A*Exp[-(y - y0 - y1 Cos[2 (x/180*Pi)])^2/(w0 + w1 Cos[2 x/180*Pi])^2],
       {A, {y0, 0.04}, {y1, 0.00}, {w0, 0.03}, {w1, 0.01}},
       {x, y}
      ];
Show[
     ListPointPlot3D[data],
     Plot3D[fit["BestFit"], {x, 0, 180}, {y, 0, 0.1}]
    ]
```

**EDIT:**

What I decided to do for now is using a `DensityPlot` of the data with the `ContourPlot` of the fit (similar to Rahul Narain's answer). This does not really show the quality of the model, so I will add other plots, candidates are

- residuals vs. predicted values (similar to chris's answer)
- distribution of residuals (chris's answer)
- Q-Q plot using `QuantilePlot[fit["FitResiduals"]]`
- the plot Rahul Narain suggested

[image]

Comment: you might want to try variations of `PlotStyle -> Directive[Yellow, Specularity[White, 20], Opacity[0.3]]` and possibly `BoxRatios -> {1, 1, 1}`

Comment: A standard--and very effective--way to show the *fit* is to plot the *residuals* (equal to actual - estimated) against $x$ and $y$.  For a good fit they should cluster evenly and randomly around the $xy$ plane.  Because there's no question about where that plane lies, you don't even need the third dimension. For instance, many people map out the residuals in 2D using scaled and/or colored point symbols to represent their sizes and signs.

Comment: @whuber: I think this is what I was looking for. I was playing with the residuals, but plotting them vs. the actual values (chris's answer) gives some interesting insights. Thanks a lot

Comment: The file can't access now

Comment: Thanks, I updated the link.

Answer (score 43, accepted):

If what you want to visualize is how good the fit is, then you should do as @whuber suggests and plot the residuals, that is, the difference between the data and the fitted function. Below, each data point is drawn as a point with area proportional to the magnitude of the residual. Red means that the data value is higher than the fit; blue means the data is lower. For context, the contours of the fit are plotted in the background.

```
residual[{x_, y_, z_}] := Evaluate[z - fit["BestFit"]]
rmax = Max[(Abs@residual@#) & /@ data];
residualPoint[p : {px_, py_, pz_}] := Module[{r},
  r = residual[p]/rmax;
  {AbsolutePointSize[10 Sqrt@Abs@r], 
   ColorData["ThermometerColors"][(r + 1)/2], Point[{px, py}]}]
Show[ContourPlot[fit["BestFit"], {x, 0, 180}, {y, 0, 0.1}, 
  AspectRatio -> 1, ContourShading -> None], 
 Graphics[Flatten[residualPoint /@ data]]]
```

[image]

There does seem to be a little bit of systematic bias in the residuals. If I had to guess, I'd say the fitted function tends to overestimate the data at the left and right ends of the "ridge", and underestimates the data at the lower corners. And perhaps the ridge ought to form a narrower "V". However, I am not a statistician.

Anyway, if you want to both visualize the shape of the fit and also indicate how far it is from the data simultaneously, you could lay these residual markers right on top of your 3D plot.

```
residualPoint3D[p : {x_, y_, z_}] := 
 Evaluate@Module[{r}, r = residual[p]/rmax;
   {AbsolutePointSize[2 + 8 Sqrt@Abs@r], 
    ColorData["ThermometerColors"][(r + 1)/2], 
    Point[{x, y, fit["BestFit"] + 1*^-5}]}]
Show[Plot3D[Evaluate@fit["BestFit"], {x, 0, 180}, {y, 0, 0.1}, 
  Mesh -> 5, MeshFunctions -> {#3 &}, MeshStyle -> Gray, 
  Lighting -> {{"Ambient", White}}], 
 Graphics3D[Flatten[residualPoint3D /@ data]]]
```

[image]

Comment: +1. It is useful at this stage to plot the residuals against the fit: that will make your comments more precise.  BTW, `fit["FitResiduals"]` is a built-in way to obtain the residuals.

Comment: I think I misunderstood your comment. @chris seems to have taken care of it though. :)

Comment: @jenson: Please have a look at my edited answer.

Comment: I really like the simplicity of the first plot compared to the 3d plots. Even though I think whuber's comment and Chris' answer are worth reading, you stand out with the simplicity of your visualization. One plot that shows the fit and the residuals without a lot of colors, lines or perspectives.

Comment: @jenson: I think that's what exactly what whuber meant by plotting in "the $xy$ plane... You don't even need the third dimension." 2D is nice because you don't have to deal with things like occlusions and foreshortening that could obscure the data. I'm reminded of [whuber's remarkably simple but illuminating graphic](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/11134/484) showing the vote counts of the moderator election.

Comment: Even though the other answers are good too, I will go with yours, since it really gives a useful and simple way of presenting the data. Thanks

Comment: This is a off-topic question, but I don't understand what `residualPoint[p : {px_, py_, pz_}] := Module[{r}, r = residual[p]/rmax` means? particularly, what the `p :` means in the argument?

Answer (score 26):

I would try

```
  plt=Show[ListPointPlot3D[data, ColorFunction -> "Rainbow"], 
  Plot3D[fit["BestFit"], {x, 0, 180}, {y, 0, 0.1}, 
  PlotStyle -> 
  Directive[Yellow, Specularity[White, 20], Opacity[0.3]]], 
  BoxRatios -> {1, 1, 1}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Then you can change perspective?

```
  GraphicsArray[{{plt, 
  Show[plt, ViewPoint -> Front]}, {Show[plt, ViewPoint -> Top], 
  Show[plt, ViewPoint -> {1, 1, 1}]}}, ImageSize -> 600]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

**EDIT**

Following @whube's suggestion and using @ArgentoSapiens's code we see that the residual have a reasonable distribution:

```
 (Last /@ actualpredicted[[1]]) - (Last /@ actualpredicted[[2]]) // Histogram
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

With a relative error of 25 %

```
 StandardDeviation[(Last /@ actualpredicted[[1]]) - (Last /@ 
 actualpredicted[[2]])]/Mean[(Last /@ actualpredicted[[1]])]


  (* 0.24 *)
```

If we look at the distribution of residual versus the actual value:

```
  {(Last /@ 
   actualpredicted[[1]]), (Last /@ actualpredicted[[1]]) - (Last /@ 
   actualpredicted[[2]])} // Transpose // ListPlot
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

We do find a bias for higher values.

And since I am stealing shamelessly from the other answers,
a mixture of them all yields

```
  plt2 = With[{actualpredicted = {data, 
  Transpose[
  Append[Transpose[fit["Data"][[All, {1, 2}]]], 
   fit["PredictedResponse"]]]}}, 
  Show[ListPointPlot3D[actualpredicted, ColorFunction -> "Rainbow"], 
  plt, Graphics3D[{Opacity[0.25], 
  Line /@ Transpose[actualpredicted]}], BoxRatios -> {1, 1, 1}]]

  GraphicsGrid[{{plt2, 
  Show[plt2, ViewPoint -> Front]}, {Show[plt2, ViewPoint -> Top], 
  Show[plt2, ViewPoint -> {1, 1, 1}]}}, ImageSize -> 600]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: Thanks a lot. With the plot where you see the bias you might be on to something. The data is actually a histogram and the bias might be binning related.

Comment: I checked the data again. The "line" in your "distribution of residual versus the actual value" plot appears cause you plot the actual data point. If the data point is very large, the deviation from the fitted function is also large. That seems to be the reason for this "line" in the plot. Using the predicted value instead, leads to a rather symmetric distribution of the values

Answer (score 25):

I like to draw the predicted and actual responses and connect them with a little line. That shows where the fit is good and where it isn't.

```
With[{ actualpredicted={ data, Transpose[ Append[ Transpose[ fit["Data"][[All,{1,2}]]],
                                                  fit["PredictedResponse"] ] ] } },
     Show[ ListPointPlot3D[actualpredicted, PlotStyle -> {Red, Gray}],
           Graphics3D[{Opacity[0.25], Line /@ Transpose[actualpredicted]}]
         ]
    ]
```

[image]

Comment: +1 We should merge our answers for best effect ;-)

Answer (score 22):

Edit: actually this is very redundant with chris' answer. I keep it for the moment though.

I like to style the data points according to offset from the fit:

```
Show[{
 Plot3D[fit[x, y], {x, 0, 175}, {y, 0., 0.1},     
        ColorFunction -> "DarkRainbow", 
        PlotStyle -> None, 
        Mesh -> 10],   
 ListPointPlot3D[Partition[data, 1], 
                 Ticks -> Automatic, 
                 Axes -> True,  
                 FillingStyle -> Thin,     
                 Filling ->Thread[Range[1, Length[data]] -> 
                      Table[fit[Sequence @@ data[[i, {1, 2}]]], 
                            {i, 1, Length[data]}]],
                 ColorFunction -> Function[{x, y, z}, 
                 Blend[{{-.0004, Darker@Red}, {-.0002, Red}, {0, Green}, {.0002, 
                 Blue}, {.0004, Lighter@Blue}}, z - fit[x, y]]],
                 ColorFunctionScaling -> False, 
                 BoxRatios -> Automatic,     
                 FillingStyle -> Directive[LightGreen, Thick]]
      }]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: this is not redundant and quite useful as it shows systematic bias in 2D.