# How can I superimpose a set of points on a ContourPlot?

Tags: plotting

I am familiar with *Mathematica* to a certain extent, but its subtleties still elude me.

**Currently I am trying to solve the following problem:**
The function $f(x,y)$ is continuous. I know how to create a contourplot of it. I also have a list of points `{{x,y}, ...}` which I would like to insert into my contour plot.

**Background:**
I am working on some genetic algorithms and would like to visualize how the population converges to the global optimum. This is why I would like to show the population (or at least the best candidate of each generation) in the contour plot.

How could this be done?

Comment: A contour plot is 2D. How do you want to include 3D points in it?

Comment: contour plot projects onto the x-y plane the levels of a function in two variables. It is 2D as opposed to your triples. You could project them too using `ListContourPlot` or use a the contour plot as a texture for the x-y plane (see [related](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/938/how-to-make-a-drop-shadow-for-graphics3d-objects/940#940))

Comment: i did not mean to use 3D data - my question was perhaps somewhat confusion. Just wanted to plot the population - only (x,y) values. I will adjust the phrasing accordingly

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I guess one should use the following plot to visualize convergence. For optimization consider this example, and collect the points during `NMinimize` evaluation.

```
Clear[f]
f[x_, y_] := 20 Sin[\[Pi]/2 (x - 2 \[Pi])] +
20 Sin[\[Pi]/2 (y - 2 \[Pi])] + (x - 2 \[Pi])^2 + (y - 2 \[Pi])^2;
pts = Reap[sol = NMinimize[f[x, y], {x, y}, 
  Method -> {"SimulatedAnnealing", "PerturbationScale" -> 3, 
    "BoltzmannExponent" -> 
     Function[{i, df, f0}, -df/(Exp[i/10])]}, 
  StepMonitor :> (Sow[{x, y}])];];
```

Let's visualize it. Here blue is the starting point and red is the global optimum.

```
ContourPlot[f[x, y], {x, -2, 7}, {y, -2, 7}, Contours -> 10, 
ColorFunction -> "BlueGreenYellow", PlotLegends -> Automatic, 
Epilog -> ({Red, PointSize[.01], Arrowheads[0.025], 
Arrow /@ Partition[pts[[2, 1]], 2, 1], Yellow, 
Point /@ pts[[2, 1]], Blue, PointSize[.02], Point[pts[[2, 1, 1]]],
 Red, PointSize[.02], Point[{x, y} /. sol[[2]]]}),ContourLabels -> True]
```

[image]

**Note:**

For plotting 3D points on a 2D surface, check out this wonderful post by [Rahul Narain](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/17046/how-to-visualize-3d-fit).

BR

Comment: this is beautiful. Problem is I wrote my own genetic algorithm in C++ and output the different evolutionary steps into a CSV-file. This is why I need to plot a list of data.

Comment: still i had no idea sth like that wos doable. Beautiful :)

Comment: @Probabilitnator please note `pts` are just the points visited by the algorithm. So what you need to do is import the points of your genetic steps into Mathematica. CSV import is easy.

Comment: now i see. Thanks now this is even more beautiful <3 !

Comment: is this Rastrigin's function you are using - this is actually the one I wanted to do the plot for :D

Comment: @chris mostly copied from docs :( Thx though....

Answer (score 2):

Since presumably f[x,y] is the same for the GA result as the contour plot, you can display the points at which your GA has been evaluated on the contour plot in this way:

```
gaPoints= Tuples[Range@12, 2];
f[{x_, y_}] := {Sin@x, Cos@y}

g1 = ListPlot[gaPoints];
g2 = ContourPlot[f[{x, y}], {x, 0, 4 Pi}, {y, 0, 4 Pi}];
```

And plot the two graphs as:

```
Show[g2, g1]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: so basically I am just overlapping the two plots ?? - this is easier than I would have thought and exactly what I am looking for. Could you perhaps explain some of the syntax ? (why use 'Sin@x' )

Comment: Yes indeed you can combine plots by simply overlapping them :) `Sin@x` is just a short form of `Sin[x]`.

Comment: how can I get rid of that grid ?

Comment: You can use the ContourLines Options, `ContourPlot[f[{x, y}], {x, 0, 4 Pi}, {y, 0, 4 Pi}, 
 ContourLines -> False]`