# Insert points in a ContourPlot

Tags: plotting

This is my code

```
ContourPlot[{y^4 - 3 x*y^2 + x^3}, {x, -2.5, 2.5}, {y, -2, 2}, 
 Contours -> {Automatic, 50}, BoundaryStyle -> Directive[Red, Thick], 
 ContourShading -> None, Axes -> True, AxesLabel -> {x, y}, 
 PlotRange -> {{-3, 3}, {-2.5, 2.5}}, 
 LabelStyle -> Directive[Blue, Bold], Frame -> False]
```

[image]

And I want to insert following points (color=green and thick):

> P1=(1.5,1.5)
>   P2=(1.5,-1.5)

Each point shall be be labeled with the value:

> -1.6875

This value shall be visible in the Plot.

Comment: Also related: [22305](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/22305/how-can-i-superimpose-a-set-of-points-on-a-contourplot)

Answer (score 7):

You could use `Epilog`, something like:

```
pts = {{1.5, 1.5}, {1.5, -1.5}};
ContourPlot[{y^4 - 3 x*y^2 + x^3}, {x, -2.5, 2.5}, {y, -2, 2}, 
 Contours -> {Automatic, 50}, BoundaryStyle -> Directive[Red, Thick], 
 ContourShading -> None, Axes -> True, AxesLabel -> {x, y}, 
 PlotRange -> {{-3, 3}, {-2.5, 2.5}}, 
 LabelStyle -> Directive[Blue, Bold], Frame -> False, 
 Epilog -> { PointSize[0.05], Green, Point[#] & /@ pts, Black, 
   Text["-1.6875", #] & /@ pts}]
```

Result:

[image]

Comment: Though not exactly the question, I prefer Epilog -> {Green, PointSize[0.02], 
   Tooltip[Point[{{1.5, 1.5}, {1.5, -1.5}}], -1.6785]}]. The green points then behave exactly like the contour lines: the value appears when the mouse is over them.