# Label points in a contour plot

Tags: plotting

```
pts = {{1.5, 1.5}, {1.5, -1.5}, {2.5, 0}, {2.5, 1.94}, {2.5, -1.94}, {-2.5, 0}, {2, 2},
     {-2, 2}, {2, -2}, {-2, -2}, {2.5, 2}, {-2.5, 2}, {-2.5, -2}, {2.5, -2}};

ContourPlot[{y^4 - 3 x y^2 + x^3}, {x, -2.5, 2.5}, {y, -2, 2}, 
     Contours -> {Automatic, 50}, BoundaryStyle -> Directive[Red, Thick], Frame -> False, 
     ContourShading -> None, Axes -> True, AxesLabel -> {x, y},
     PlotRange -> {{-3, 3}, {-2.5, 2.5}}, LabelStyle -> Directive[Blue, Bold], 
     Epilog -> {PointSize[0.015], Green, Point[#] & /@ pts, Black, 
               Text["-1.6875", "-1.6875", "15.625", "15.625", "1.5625", "-1.5625",
                "0", "32", "0", "32", "1.625", "30.375", "30.375", "1.625"] & /@ pts, 
     PlotLegends -> "Expressions"}]`
```

[image]

My problem is now that I have more than 2 points. And (almost) every point has a different value. Example

> {1.5,1.5} shall be named -1.6875
>
> {1.5,-1.5} shall be named -1.6875
>
> {2.5,0} shall be named 15.625
>
> {2.5,0} shall be named 1.5625
>
> It continues this way.

`PlotLegends` shall show the `Expressions` (Min, Max, Saddle point). Min, Max and Saddle point shall have three different colors. The points you pick don't matter. I simply want to know how it's done. Take some for Min, some for Max and one for the Saddle point. But don't confuse the right "value" as a text output (it shall be automatic the right form)

Comment: Aren't you worried that, by the looks of the image you uploaded, you are getting error messages ? And you are not, judging by the post, investigating what caused them

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! I suggest the following: 1) As you receive help, try to give it too, by answering questions in your area of expertise. 2) Read the [faq](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/tour)! 3) When you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://i.stack.imgur.com/eNrdG.png), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge. Also, please remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, by [clicking the checkmark sign](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/)!

Comment: Perhaps `MapThread` could be of help (instead of `/@`).  And perhaps `PointLegend[{Red, Green, Blue}, {"Min", "Max", "Saddle"}]`. -- Some parts are not completely clear.  You simply want to know how what is done?  And I don't understand the last sentence.  Can you help?

Comment: Considering your recent [question](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/84712/insert-points-in-a-contourplot/84714), maybe it is not a good idea to label all points with their values on the plot. You can use your color code and label them 1,2,3, and have a separate table to write values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

EDIT: Added legends for max, min, and saddle points.

```
pts = {
   {1.5, 1.5}, {1.5, -1.5}, {2.5, 0},
   {2.5, 1.94}, {2.5, -1.94}, {-2.5, 0},
   {2, 2}, {-2, 2}, {2, -2}, {-2, -2},
   {2.5, 2}, {-2.5, 2}, {-2.5, -2},
   {2.5, -2}};

f[x_, y_] = y^4 - 3 x y^2 + x^3;
```

The function is symmetric in `y`

```
f[x, y] == f[x, -y]
```

> True

```
FindMaximum[{f[x, y], -2.5 <= x <= 2.5, -2 <= y <= 2},
  {x, y}] // Rationalize[#, 10^-7] &
```

> {32, {x -> -2, y -> 2}}

```
maxPts = {{x, y}, {x, -y}} /. %[[-1]]
```

> {{-2, 2}, {-2, -2}}

```
FindMinimum[{f[x, y], -5/2 <= x <= 5/2, -2 <= y <= 2},
  {x, y}, WorkingPrecision -> 50] // N
```

> {-1.6875, {x -> 1.5, y -> -1.5}}

```
minPts = {{x, y}, {x, -y}} /. %[[-1]]
```

> {{1.5, -1.5}, {1.5, 1.5}}

```
Solve[{D[f[x, y], x] == 0, D[f[x, y], y] == 0,
    -2.5 <= x <= 2.5, -2 <= y <= 2}, {x, y}] // Union // Quiet
```

> {{x -> 0, y -> 0}, {x -> 1.5, y -> -1.5}, {x -> 1.5, y -> 1.5}}

```
saddlePts = {{x, y}} /. %[[1]]
```

> {{0, 0}}

```
otherPts = Complement[pts, maxPts, minPts, saddlePts];
```

`Point[pts]` is more efficient than `Point[#]&/@pts` and your syntax is wrong for `Text`

```
n = 1;
Legended[
 ContourPlot[
  f[x, y], {x, -2.5, 2.5}, {y, -2, 2},
  Contours -> {Automatic, 50},
  BoundaryStyle -> Directive[Gray, Thick],
  Frame -> False,
  ContourShading -> None,
  Axes -> True,
  AxesLabel -> {x, y},
  PlotRange -> {{-3, 3}, {-2.5, 2.5}},
  LabelStyle -> Directive[Blue, Bold],
  Epilog -> {
    PointSize[0.015],
    Darker[Green],
    Point[otherPts],
    Text[
       Style[ToString[f @@ #],
        Bold,
        Darker[Green],
        Background -> Yellow],
       #, {0, (-1)^(n++) 1.5}] & /@
     otherPts,
    Red,
    Point[maxPts],
    Text[
       Style[ToString[f @@ #],
        Bold,
        Red,
        Background -> Yellow],
       #, {0, (-1)^(n++) 1.5}] & /@ maxPts,
    Blue,
    Point[minPts],
    Text[
       Style[ToString[f @@ #],
        Bold,
        Blue,
        Background -> Yellow],
       #, {0, (-1)^(n++) 1.5}] & /@ minPts,
    Lighter[Purple],
    Point[saddlePts],
    Text[
       Style[ToString[f @@ #],
        Bold,
        Lighter[Purple],
        Background -> Yellow],
       #, {0, (-1)^(n++) 1.5}] & /@ saddlePts}],
 PointLegend[
  {Red, Lighter[Purple], Blue},
  {"Max", "Saddle", "Min"}]]
```

[image]